# Let $f$ be a function such that $f''$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and $f(a)f'(a)\geq f(b)f'(b)$, prove: $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)f''(x)dx\leq0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a function such that $f''$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and $f(a)f'(a)\geq f(b)f'(b)$.

Prove that: $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)f''(x)dx\leq0$

(Disclaimer this isn't a homework question)

I tried using integration by parts but I got to $0=0$ which was unhelpful:
$$\int_a^bf(x)f''(x)dx=\left[f(x)f'(x) \right]_a^b-\int_a^b(f'(x))^2dx\\\implies\int_a^b(f'(x))^2dx=\left[f(x)f'(x) \right]_a^b-\int_a^bf(x)f''(x)dx\\\implies\int_a^bf(x)f''(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)f''(x)dx\implies0=0$$

I don't see any other way to answer this question directly, I'd appreciate any help or possible direction.

Thanks.

Comment: To add to the answer, you will find that the inequality $f(a)f'(a) \ge f'(b)f(b)$ does not provide any useful information. You can also deduce this by noting that the integral is invariant under the substitution $x \mapsto a+b-x$, so WLOG, we can make any function satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your last part is like a circle. You took
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)f''(x)dx$$
and used integration by parts, but then on the right hand side you do again integration by parts, but in the other directs (so you come back from where you started).

Instead think about the function $f'(x)^2$ and as a hint: what do you know about $x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and use that $f\geq g$ implies that
$$\int f(x)dx\geq \int g(x)dx.$$